How To Manage Or Update State From Lower To Higher Order Component?
I want to update the state of a function component from a lower order component. However, I have been unsuccessful at doing this. Sometimes, React state management confuses me.
In the code sample I provide, when someone clicks on a fruit-item, it can be edited. Apparently, React does not fire the callback inside the useEffect hook. Neither has the state been updated using the _finishEdit function.
Thank you for your help !
The following is the code sample, and also linked on Expo Snacks.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, Modal, TextInput, Pressable } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const FRUITS = [{ name: 'Banana', }, { name: 'Pineapple', }, { name: 'Strawberry', }];
  const [data, setData] = useState(FRUITS);

  const _addNew = () => {
    const dataCpy = [...data];
    dataCpy.push({ name: 'Another item', });
    setData(dataCpy);
  };

  const _onEdit = (edit, ind) => {
    const dataCpy = [...data];
    dataCpy[ind] = {name: edit};
    setData(dataCpy);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      { data.map((item: any, ind: number) => <Item title={item.name} key={ind} onEdit={_onEdit} />) }

      <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={_addNew}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonTextLarge}> + Add new item</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;


const Item = ({ title, key, onEdit }: { title: string, key: number, onEdit: (edit: string, ind: number) => {} }) => {
  const [text, onTitleChanged] = React.useState(title);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onEdit(text, key);
  }, [text, onEdit, key]);

  const _toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

  const _onFinishEdit = () => {
    onEdit(text, key);
    _toggleModal();
  };

  return (<>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ _toggleModal }>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <Modal transparent={true} visible={modalVisible} onRequestClose={ _toggleModal }>
      <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <View style={styles.modalView}>

          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={onTitleChanged}
            placeholder="useless placeholder"
            value={text}
          />

          <Pressable style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]} onPress={_onFinishEdit}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText} >Finish edit</Text>
          </Pressable>

        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  </>);

};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    margin: 6,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#00c2fe',
    padding: 12,
    borderRadius: 3,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 3,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    padding: 9,
    elevation: 2,
    marginTop: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#5bddb9',
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  buttonTextLarge: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});



I have post the question to ChatGPT.
The following is the answer I have gotten.
To address the issues in your React Native code, we need to ensure that the onEdit function is properly updating the state of the parent component when a fruit item is edited. There are a few adjustments required to make this work correctly:

Pass the ind to the Item component properly: Currently, you are passing key which is a reserved prop in React and cannot be accessed inside the component. Instead, pass ind explicitly.
Fix the useEffect dependency: Ensure that useEffect only triggers when necessary. It should trigger when text changes and not when onEdit or key changes, as they are stable.
Update the state correctly in App: Ensure that the onEdit function properly updates the state in the parent component.


Please don’t post AI generated answers.

OK - the AI seems to get the answer right. I even wonder how Stack OverFlow plans to integrate AI on its website. Don't you, @ChukwujiobiCanon?

I HOPE Stack OverFlow will not come with some of its bad rules again.
